# Реализация включения/выключения на Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Написал скрипт, при нажатии на который будет открываться таб. Всё работает. Думал напишу функцию, которая будет закрывать таб. Написал, не работает. В чём проблема?
Сам я новичок в js, применил простой копипаст и интуитивно поменял значения. Сильно не ругайтесь.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".tabs-2-triggers__item").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".tabs-2-triggers__item").removeClass("tabs-2-triggers__item--active");
    $(".tabs-2-content__item").removeClass("tabs-2-content__item--active");

    $(this).addClass("tabs-2-triggers__item--active");
    $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("tabs-2-content__item--active");
  });
  // Вкл/выкл
  $(".tabs-2-triggers__item--active").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".tabs-2-triggers__item").removeClass(this);
    $(".tabs-2-content__item").removeClass(this);
    console.log("Сработало");

    $(this).removeClass("tabs-2-triggers__item--active");
    $($(this).attr("href")).removeClass("tabs-2-content__item--active");
  });

});
```

```css
.tabs-2-triggers {
  display: flex;
}
.tabs-2-triggers__item {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.tabs-2-triggers__item--active {
  background: #eee;
}
.tabs-2-content__item {
  display: none;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}
.tabs-2-content__item--active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dedic-nav">
            <div class="dedic-filter">
              <div class="tabs-2-triggers">
                <a href="#tab-2-1" class="tabs-2-triggers__item">TAB 1</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dedic-filters">
            <div class="tabs-2">
              <div class="tabs-2-content">
                <div id="tab-2-1" class="tabs-2-content__item">Контент 1</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема сделать через classToggle()?

Comment: `$(".tabs-2-triggers__item").removeClass(this);` - https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: @Igor, куда это писать? Я в js 0 потому и написал вопрос на форуме.

Comment: Никуда. `removeClass` не вызывается с DOM-элементом.

Comment: @Igor, хорошо, что тогда стоит сделать?